# Nuget update did not update csproj file

Tags: c#, package, nuget, csproj

When I update a Nuget package, it seems that my csproj file did not update properly.

In this case, I'm updating NLog from 2.1.0.0 to 3.2.0.0, but after updating the package and building the solution, I'm still getting this in my csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="NLog, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\NLog.3.2.0.0\lib\net40\NLog.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The Reference Version is 2.1.0.0, but the HintPath points to the latest folder.

Why does this happen, and how can I make sure my csproj file is updated correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: The reference version is 3.2.0.0, as it comes from DLL, that is actually referenced, not from name that is specified in `Include` attribute.